# React js - updating a list of items after initial render

Tags: .net, reactjs, server-side

I am very new to react (angular background) and am trying to render a list of items that will be updated with new items on click of a button. Regarding the following code below, the initial list is displayed (2 records), however, after onClick i can see the console.log message but the rendered items do not change. Is something wrong with this implementation?

Note: I am using server side rendering with .net.

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
items: [
    '<h1>Initial Item 1</h1>', 
    '<h1>Initial Item 2</h1>'
],
getItems: function () {
    return this.items;
},
getMoreItems: function() {
    console.log('Retrieving more items..');

    // To eventually be replaced with async call for more data
    this.items.push('<h1>Additional Item 1</h1>');
    this.items.push('<h1>Additional Item 2</h1>');
    this.items.push('<h1>Additional Item 3</h1>');
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                this.getItems().map(function(item) {
                    return (
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item}} />
                    );
                })
            }

            <button className="more btn btn-info" onClick={this.getMoreItems}>
                Get more items...
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use your component's State.

React components will automatically re-render whenever their state or props change.  `this.setState({items: items})` in your `getMoreItems` method, matched with `this.state.items` in your `getItems` method should solve the problem.

Be sure not to change the state directly though.  If you want to push new items into the state, interact with a separate array and then set that with the same `this.setState` statement.  I.e., do **not** do:  `this.state.items.push()`.

Comment: thanks. I have tried what you are suggesting but the render function is failing saying - Cannot read property 'items' of null. Does this.state have to be initialised somewhere?

Comment: nevermind - i found i needed the getInitialState function. thanks

Comment: If you want the component to have a state on it's initial render, you can use the included [`getInitialState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate) attribute (invoked the same way you do `render`).